QGIS: Changing map projection using satellite image
I have been working on a project for several weeks now, which shows the surface currents using OSCAR. I am using the following data set from NASA:https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search/granules?p=C2036880665-POCLOUD&pg[0][v]=f&pg[0][gsk]=-end_date&g=G2980533771-POCLOUD&q=OSCAR%20third%20degree%20resolution%20ocean%20surface%20currents&tl=1716302430!3!!&zoom=0
However, the data is displayed centered on the Pacific. How can I change it so that it is centered on the 0 meridian? (So that everything east of Australia is cut off and placed on the left-hand side of the section)
I have already tried using other CRS (currently using EPSG 4326), but then the Atlantic to Indian Ocean area is no longer displayed.

Does this answer your question? Shifting extent and data values of NetCDF with GDAL
